# What is an appropriate translation for "Search your feelings" from star wars

Tags: traduction

Disclaimer: I'm a native french speaker.

I wonder how the sentence "search your feelings" (which comes right after the legendary "I am your father" in Star Wars") can be translated.

I propose :

- écoute ton coeur     -- kind of distant of the original meaning maybe
- sonde tes sentiments -- bit prosaic

Neither of these satisfies me.

Comment: Cherche dans ton inconscient? - mais ce n'est pas ça non plus.

Comment: Cherche en toi ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "official" translation, from [the French version](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2s840_luke-je-suis-ton-pere_shortfilms) is:

> Lis dans ton cœur

Comment: Pretty good, too. :)

Comment: @Lambie Yes, I wouldn't find better.

Comment: I was quite close

Comment: Yes, *écoute* and *lis* are indeed equivalent here.